# Touchpad does not work after updating to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, hp

I just updated my laptop (HP zBook 15u) from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (kernel version 4.4.0-62-generic) and suddenly the touchpad does not work anymore.

USB mouse and the pointer from the keyboard work fine.
However, I would like to use the touchpad as well.

Since I am not an experienced Linux-User I didn't want to try out command lines I found in other post related to my problem without guidance.

`xinput list` gives:

```
     Virtual core pointer                    id=2   [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer         id=4   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Trackball             id=10  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                 id=13  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                  id=3   [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard        id=5   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                       id=6   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                          id=7   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                          id=8   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                       id=9   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Webcam                       id=11  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard       id=12  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                id=14  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                     id=15  [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and with `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` no touchpad is listed.

Has anyone a solution to my problem? Is it possible that I disabled the touchpad by accident? Please let me know if additional information is needed!

---

The problem 'solved itself' after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Report it as a bug to Launchpad. First check that it is not disabled by a hardware switch.

Comment: How can I check that it is not disabled by a hardware switch?